# How to replace 'colon' with 'underscore sign' in system MAC address?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Here I created a bash script to get system mac address(05:1d:48:2f:60:h6) and assigning to a variable $phyAddr. I want to replace ':' to '_' from mac address and assigned to another variable $phyAddrConvert. Here its getting mac address only. Please help me to correct replacing 'col' to 'underscore sign'.

```
phyAddr=`ifconfig | grep 'eth0' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5` 
phyAddrConvert=$phyAddr | sed "s/:/_/g";
echo $phyAddr                  # get output as 05:1d:48:2f:60:h6
echo $phyAddrConvert           # nothing will get
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with,

```
 # cat phyAddr.sh
 phyAddr=`ifconfig | grep eth0 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/:/_/g'`
 echo $phyAddr
```

your mac addr should display like this,

```
 # ./phyAddr.sh
 1A_2B_3C_4D_5E_6F
```

Answer (score 4):

```
phyAddrConvert=${phyAddr//:/_}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing this line:

```
phyAddrConvert=$phyAddr | sed "s/:/_/g";
```

with this:

```
phyAddrConvert=$(echo $phyAddr | sed "s/:/_/g")
```

should give you the result you're looking for.